# Run Jest test in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, jestjs

I created a React app with `create-react-app` version 1.4.0 and opened the resulting project in IntelliJ. Now I am attempting to run the generated test in IntelliJ as well. I get the following output when I do so:

```
/usr/bin/node /home/l/src/hello-react/node_modules/jest/bin/jest --config {\"rootDir\":\"/home/l/src/hello-react\",\"transformIgnorePatterns\":[\"/node_modules/\",\"^/home/l/bin/idea-IU-172.3544.35/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers\"],\"unmockedModulePathPatterns\":[\"^/home/l/bin/idea-IU-172.3544.35/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers\"]} --colors --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile /home/l/bin/idea-IU-172.3544.35/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-jasmine.js --testPathPattern ^/home/l/src/hello\-react/src/App\.test\.js$ --testNamePattern "^(test )?renders without crashing$"
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/l/src/hello-react/src/App.test.js: Unexpected token (7:18)
        5 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
        6 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
      > 7 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
          |                   ^
        8 | });
        9 | 

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.73s
Ran all test suites matching /^/home/l/src/hello\-react/src/App\.test\.js$/ with tests matching "^(test )?renders without crashing$".

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

I am only running the generated code. I have not modified it or written any of my own code. What do I need to do in order to be able to run this test in IntelliJ IDEA?

For reference, here are the important files:

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jest Run configuration choose:

```
jest-package: react-scripts
jest options: --env=jsdom
```

Comment: When I select `react-scripts` as the Jest Package, I get the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

**P.S.** Don't use /src for your working directory as you see image below

[image]