# Jest tests run fine from CLI, but fail in IntelliJ

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, jestjs, nrwl-nx

I have an older angular project that I'm updating and moving to nx. (NX is cool.) I'm created a new project from the tutorial and am gradually moving my files over.

With unit tests, `nx test` runs all of the unit tests in my project just fine, so it appears jest is configured correctly as far as that goes, but when I run inside IntelliJ, I get:

```
  console.error
    Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
            at Object.dispatchError (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:54:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:675:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:203:15)

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load app.component.html

    at resolvePromise (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:832:39)
```

I found this one, but not sure what it means to place jest options in Jest Run.
[Run Jest test in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455260/run-jest-test-in-intellij-idea)

I found some more, but nothing much helpful. Most seem to be getting these errors after the test completes.

It appears that jest configuration has changed a lot recently, because many of the posts I'm finding refer to out of date files.

**Update:**

A comment suggested upgrading to NX 10, which I was excited to do anyway, so I did so. Now I'm getting exactly the same error from the CLI as I am in IntelliJ. PROGRESS!!!

So I've noticed that all of the test were pretty much failing to load the same html file, so I've now created a test for just that component to try to isolate the issue. Here's the error I'm getting now.

```
  console.error
    Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
        at Object.dispatchError (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:54:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:675:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:203:15)
        at Request.onRequestError (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
        at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) undefined

      at VirtualConsole.on.e (../../node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at Object.dispatchError (../../node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:57:53)
      at Request.client.on.err (../../node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:675:20)
      at Request.onRequestError (../../node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)


Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load choose-address.component.html

    at resolvePromise (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:832:39)
    at resolvePromise (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:784:21)
    at /home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:894:21
    at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:35)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:86:33)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:145:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:40)
    at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.runTask (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:51)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:601:39)
    at ZoneTask.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:507:25)
    at invokeTask (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1671:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1697:21)
    at innerInvokeEventListeners (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:316:27)
    at invokeEventListeners (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:267:3)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTargetImpl._dispatch (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:214:9)
    at fireAnEvent (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/events.js:17:36)
    at requestErrorSteps (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:121:3)
    at Object.dispatchError (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:51:3)
    at Request.client.on.err (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:675:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at Request.onRequestError (/home/thomas/git/heavyweight-software/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
<h2>Address changed by validation.</h2>
<form  [formGroup]="chooseAddressForm">
  <mat-radio-group
      aria-label="Please choose your correct address."
      *ngFor="let address of data.contactPoints; let ix = index"
      name="selectAddress"
      formControlName="selectAddress">
    <mat-radio-button value="{{ix}}">
      {{address.street1}}<br/>
      {{address.city}}, {{address.state}} {{address.postalCode}}<br/>
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</form>

<p><span class="error">{{errorText}}</span></p>

<div class="buttonBar">
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="onButtonClick(true)">Select</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="onButtonClick(false)">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And the unit test:

```
describe('ChooseAddressComponent', () => {
  let component: ChooseAddressComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChooseAddressComponent>;

  const chooseAddressData: ChooseAddressDialogData = new ChooseAddressDialogData();
  const matDialogData = {};
  let mockMatDialogRef: MockMatDialogRef;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ChooseAddressComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatRadioModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ChooseAddressDialogData, useValue: chooseAddressData},
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: matDialogData},
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MockMatDialogRef},
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChooseAddressComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    mockMatDialogRef = TestBed.inject(MatDialogRef);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'heavyweight-software-app-choose-address',
  templateUrl: './choose-address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./choose-address.component.css']
})
export class ChooseAddressComponent implements OnInit {
  chooseAddressForm: FormGroup;
  errorText = '';

  constructor(protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChooseAddressComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ChooseAddressDialogData) { }

  get selectAddress(): AbstractControl { return this.chooseAddressForm.get('selectAddress'); }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.chooseAddressForm = new FormGroup({
      selectAddress: new FormControl(null,
        [ Validators.required])
    } );

    this.selectAddress.patchValue(0);
  }

  onButtonClick(confirmed: boolean): void {
    this.errorText = '';

    if (confirmed) {
      const idx: number = this.selectAddress.value;
      if (idx) {
        this.data.selectedIndex = idx;
        this.dialogRef.close();
      } else {
        this.errorText = 'You must select your address from the list';
      }
    } else {
      this.data.selectedIndex = null;
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Please share any ideas.

Comment: In order to run tests the same way as `nx test` IDE should be configured with same Jest config and options, the latter are shown in the question you linked. If you're unsure, don't specify any options. The error appears outside tests and doesn't make them fail, it's very likely that this also happens in `nx test` but you didn't notice it. The error means that the app does real requests, which is discouraged in tests.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about the run configuration. I set run configuration, Jest Options to --env=jsdom and reran. No change to the error.

Comment: The problem is probably related to https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/217 and https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1059 . Check suggested solutions. If you don't use the last Jest version, you can start with updating it.

Comment: @EstusFlask this is an example of a much older post (2018) that I found who's configuration information is very out of date. I went through a number of these before finally posting here.

Comment: @Thom could you try with Nx 10? We just released that basically last week and it should have full support for running Jest tests within Webstorm

Comment: @Juri Thanks. I upgraded, but the tests still won't run.

Comment: @Juri I am now unable to run tests from the CLI since upgrading. This is not going well...I'm going to try to reformat this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran the upgrade from https://nx.dev/angular/workspace/update I seem to have missed the command

`nx migrate --run-migrations=migrations.json`

so I was running with an incomplete upgrade. Running this command seems to have fixed the issue with nx test and now nx 10 is testing properly with IntelliJ as well.

Life is good! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following on project just to upgrade jest and not play around with angular version or workspace set up

```
nx migrate @nrwl/jest@10.3.2 --from=@nrwl/jest@9.5.1
npm install
nx migrate --run-migrations=migrations.json
```

Few of the file update failed.
Then manually changed following files

- jest.config.js
- apps/project/jest.config.js

https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/commit/8772ff2a6d381df029c5b98c864a75ec8c72be3f

The test are now running fine in intelliJ, ng cli & nx cli